# jQuery was not called error with Cached WCF

Tags: jquery, wcf, caching

I have spun up a WCF Service with a jQuery Ajax call. The error I get is

"jQuery182021375292306765914_1377272303506 was not called"

It works perfectly fine, until I try to add caching to the WCF, here is my .Net Code

```
    [OperationContract]
    [Description("Gets Session List")]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "GetSessionList")]
    [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor60Seconds")]
    List<Session> GetSessionList();
```

and my web.config

```
 <caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="CacheFor60Seconds" duration="3600" varyByParam="none"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

I also have  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"

and here is my JS Code

```
   var location = JSON.stringify(j$("#Filter option:selected").val());
        j$.ajax({
            cache: true,
            url: "http://localhost:57200/Service.svc/GetSessionList",
            data: "{}",
            type: "GET",               
            jsonpcallback: "SessionList",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error.Message);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                builtHtml(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                j$("#button").disabled = false;
                j$('#searchbox').removeClass('loading');
                j$("#resultsBlock").show();
            }

        });
```

If I set the WCF Cache to 1 (aka it never really caches unless I am fast), it works fine, but if I raise it to when the cached response would be triggered, the error block fires in jQuery. Calling the WCF from the browser with the caching turned on works fine so its not an issue there, its with the AJAX response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it means your server is not returning a proper `jsonp` formatted data

Comment: Well if I check my Fiddler logs, I have valid JSON coming back

Comment: `jsonp` does not return a `JSON`, it needs to return a JSON wrapped in a function call like `jQuery182021375292306765914_1377272303506({..json_data...})`

Comment: I am not following, it works if the cache is turned off, so how do I format the cached response to jsonp